# What's the proper reading order for the Tokimeki Tonight manga?

Tags: tokimeki-tonight, ribon

What's the proper reading order for the *Tokimeki Tonight* shoujo manga series about a half-vampire, half-werewolf girl written by Ikeno Koi? When should 「ときめきミッドナイト」(*Tokimeki Midnight*), 「星のゆくえ」(*Hoshi no Yukue*),  「真壁俊の事情」(*Makabe Shun no Jijou*), and「江藤望里の駆け落ち」(*Etou Moori no Kakeochi*) be read in comparison with the main series?

Are there any other prequels, sequels, side stories, or spin-offs that

- were published in the [*tankoubon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank%C5%8Dbon) of another series by the same mangaka (i.e. tacked on as a one-shot at the back of the book)?
- ran in *Ribon*, *Cookie*, or such sister manga magazines but have not yet been published in *tankoubon* book form?
- were published outside of the Ribon Mascot Comics (RMC) line?

Comment: Since you tagged this with the "ribon" tag, are you only concerned about the Ribon published series? Tokimeki Midnight was published in Cookie. So unless you question is specific to Ribon series, or the magazine itself, there's really no need to include the tag.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ, thanks for letting me know it ran in Cookie. I saw that it's published under Shuueisha's Ribon Mascot Comics (RMC) line. There was no series title tag for this series and since I shouldn't make a meta tag without precedent, I saw that there is a shounen-jump tag and thought a ribon tag would thereby fit with precedent. I'm definitely interested to know which of these ran in RIbon magazine and which didn't.

Comment: [Tokimeki Tonight Library](http://tokimeki.medoroa.net/), an English fan-site contains a really good explanation of all series's publications including prequels, sequels, side stories, and spin-offs. Note that it is also full with **spoilers** though. (Feel free to use that as a reference when answering, probably I'll answer it when I have time to compile the information)